# Real life example for underscore.js _.defer

Tags: underscore.js

Could anyone give simplest real usage (source code) example on how to use [_.defer](http://underscorejs.org/#defer) for "Useful for performing expensive computations or HTML rendering in chunks without blocking the UI thread from updating"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## These are equivalent

```
_.defer(fn);
setTimeout(fn, 1);
```

So defer is simply a one millisecond setTimeout. (It's got a few more convenience features but those aren't important here.)